# keeping constraints when replacing a view by an other view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application, I have :

- The main Window, containing a "custom view", which is an NSView
  dropped in IB.
- A View Controller + an other nib, containing a view and some
  controls.

When the app loads, I am using :

`initWithNibName:nibName andReplaceView:(the custom view) resize:YES`

To replace the custom view. I know there is an option `placeholder` for the views in IB, but I do not know how to use it, and my app works well this way...
... except that the loaded view does not inherit the layout constraints of the replaced view.

**How can I fix this ?**

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot that the function was mine... I wrote it a long time ago in a category. Here is the code :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibName andReplaceView:(NSView*)aView resize:(BOOL)resize
{
    // 1. Loading the bundle
    if (self = [self initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil])
    {
        [self replaceView:aView resize:resize]; 
    }

    return self;    
}

- (void)replaceView:(NSView*)aView resize:(BOOL)resize
{
    if (resize)
    {
        NSRect insertionFrame = [aView frame];
        [[self view] setFrame:insertionFrame];
    }
    else
    {
        NSRect insertionFrame = [aView frame];
        insertionFrame.size.width = [[self view] frame].size.width;
        insertionFrame.size.height = [[self view] frame].size.height;

        [[self view] setFrame:insertionFrame];
    }

    NSView* supView = [aView superview];
    [supView replaceSubview:aView with:[self view]];
}
```

Comment: `- initWithNibName:andReplaceView:resize:` does not exist….

Comment: `-replaceView:resize:` is also custom, so we have no way of knowing what it does.

Comment: @TomDalling I have updated my post. Sorry. I wrote them over 2 or 3 years ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace a view, it removes all the layout constraints attached to the old view.

Personally, I just put the new view inside the old view. Here is some code I've used:

```
@implementation SJPlaceholderView

-(void) fillWithView:(NSView*)view {
    NSParameterAssert(view);

    view.frame = self.bounds;
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self addSubview:view];

    [self addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];

    [self addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];
}

@end
```

This makes sure the inner view frame matches the outer view frame exactly. All the layout constraints on the outer view are still in effect.

You could also try to loop through all the constraints of the old view, and apply them to the new view. Most of the constraints will be on the view itself, or the superview, but they could theoretically be on any of the ancestor views.

Comment: Adding the viwe on top of the old one is a good idea. Resources are less of an issue nowadays. Will the added view resize the same way as the old, underlying one ?

Comment: @Adeline Yes, the added views frame is constrained so that it always matches the underlying views frame.

Comment: Last question (because I can't make it work) fillWithView is to be called on the old or the new view ?

Comment: I have uopdated my code with the function I built based on your post. When using it, I do not see anything appearing on the window. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Done. I saw my typo. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was incredibly helpful. I wound up taking this and using it to resize the parent view based on the child frame. With auto layout it now scales the parent to fill the child. Your example really pushed me in the right direction.